# Android: how evenly space components within RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

I am trying to organize 3 LinearLayouts, such that one is justified to the left, one to the right, and the 3rd is between the two with equal amount of blank space on either side.   I think I wrap these in a RelativeLayout to accomplish this.  Then set one layout to alignParentLeft and the 2nd layout to alignParentRight.  But for the 3rd layout, I would like to set layout_marginLeft = (RelativeLayout.width - (layout1.width + layout2.width + layout3.width))/2.  Though, I don't see how to do this in xml.  Any suggestions?

*Edit.  Based on suggestions, I am now using a LinearLayout.  This is closer to working, but the 3 Layouts are not evenly spaced, and the right layout is not right justified.  Below is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="4dip"
        android:paddingBottom="4dip"
        android:background="#50000000"
        android:visibility="visible">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <ImageButton 
                    android:id="@+id/open"
                    android:src="@drawable/open"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/prev"
                android:src="@drawable/prev"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ImageButton>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalpages"
                android:text="0 of 0"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF">
            </TextView>
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:src="@drawable/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/zoomout"
                android:src="@drawable/zoomout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ImageButton>
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/zoomin"
                android:src="@drawable/zoomin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a LinearLayout instead of the RelativeLayout and use layout_weight attribute.
You might need to set the layout_width to 0dip and then set the weight to something like 0.33

Edit:
Yes you can use a weight 1 or any other equal weight below 1.
example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="string 1 for test...."
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="string 2 for test...."
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="string 3 for test...."
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just to append to this answer: Go with a LinearLayout (the three LinearLayouts within a LinearLayout), set all of the widths to fill_parent, and give the inner three layouts `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Comment: Thank you, this has gotten me closer, but doesn't quite work for me.  This forces the 3 linearlayouts to all be the same size, but my linearlayouts have different contents.  Please see my edit.

Comment: So you have three buttons and I am guessing that those three buttons are of not the same width. This will be a tricky case. I would suggest bringing down the image sizes so that all the buttons look good and not cropped out. Look twitter/facebook app for example. If that is not possible then decide what has to be the minimum width of each button and specify them[depends on screen size too]. And all I can suggest after that is to play around and see what works best for you.

Comment: I did not see your edited post. So for the view to be right justified or whatever you might want you need to use layout_gravity on the child layout and gravity on the parent and mention what all you want to support

Comment: Post is now edited.  For some reason layout_gravity:"right", does not force the 3rd layout to be right justified.

Comment: I just tested it and it works for my textviews. So can you check if you are using any other gravity fields on the parents or doing something else. I also changed my layout above to reflect my layout.

Comment: I believe the reason it works for your TextViews is that you added the layout parameter at the TextView level.  And your linear layouts all take up 1/3rd of the screen. So, The TextViews are properly justified within their LinearLayout, which happens to look correct, because the LinerLayouts are so big.  This won't work for my variable sized LinearLayouts.  I'm confused as to why adding the android:layout_gravity to my LinearLayouts is ineffective.

Comment: No that will also work. But the thing is that although you are right aligning the linear layout itself, the imagebutton which is inside that layout is not right aligned. So since your inner linear layout is occupying 1/3rd of the screen, it will appear that the layout is not right aligned. So change the layout_gravity of the image button which is inside your linear layout.

Comment: Works great for vertical views too, if you set the layout_height to 0dp