# How can I evenly space my ImageViews in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-imageview, android-relativelayout, spacing

I had a Android application built in which I had 3 `ImageView`s placed horizontally across a `LinearLayout`, they were placed with a `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` such that they had an even spread in the layout.

Now I have to switch to use a `RelativeLayout` (because I want to overlap another image and that can't be done with a `LinearLayout`) so I want to start with replicating the same effect of having the 3 `ImageView`s evenly spread/scaled across the parent layout, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I feel like I need to make use of the [`android:scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)... maybe center crop:

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Which sounds good but I can't seem to get it to work right... *Any thoughts on how I would achieve this even spread of `ImageView`s across my `RelativeLayout`*?

Snippet of code right now:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/dragcircle"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:tag="circle"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:adjustViewBounds="false"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:src="@drawable/circle" />
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/dragsquare"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:tag="square"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dragcircle"
       android:adjustViewBounds="false"
       android:src="@drawable/square" />
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/dragtriangle"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:tag="triangle"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dragsquare"
       android:adjustViewBounds="false"
       android:src="@drawable/triangle" />
```

---

Note: I can't find a question with the same constraints as this one on SO. There are a number of questions like:

[Android: how evenly space components within RelativeLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338792/android-how-evenly-space-components-within-relativelayout)
and
[android RelativeLayout, equal spacing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765170/android-relativelayout-equal-spacing)

But if you check out the details you'll see that they are people who have not considered the `LinearLayout` as an option for equal spacing and switching layout types ends up being the solution. I have, I was using it, but it **does not** work for me because I need to overlap an image:

Note the example, I have 3 `ImageView`s with basic shapes, but I also have a 4<sup>th</sup> `ImageView` (it starts hidden) which is overlapping the middle one. This is why I must use a `RelativeLayout`

[image]

Comment: why you don't use the relativeLayout , and inside it , use the LinearLayout ( in order to use the `layout_weigt` ) option , and then you can overlap your new imageview in the parent Layout ( which is the relativeLayout)

Comment: That solution won't make the overlapped images scale in proportion to the image it's going to overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going to want to go back to your original LinearLayout to meet all of your needs here.

If the size of your fourth image must match one of your existing image then either you'd want to create a resource that is a composite of the two images to swap to when it needs to be overlaid or replace your center ImageView with a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout that contains the ImageView. When you need to add the fourth image, add it to that layout.

Something like:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/dragcircle"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:tag="circle"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:src="@drawable/circle" />
    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/centerimagewrapper"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1" >
       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/dragsquare"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:tag="square"
          android:src="@drawable/square" />
       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/arrow"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/arrow"
          android:visibility="invisible" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/dragtriangle"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:tag="triangle"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/triangle" />
```

Comment: As to the "composite" of the two images... not sure what you mean, but they need to be seperate images. The blue circle will be "dragged" off, then after it's gone the green arrow will become visable and take focus and can be interacted with. I didn't consider swapping the middle `ImageView` for a `RelativeLayout` containing my two `ImageView`s... It's a lot of containers in containers, but that might just work. I'll give it a try.

Comment: You can also write a custom view or layout which explicitly positions things where you need them. That's probably more effort than it's worth just to avoid one extra view, but if you find the hierarchy growing even more complex it's a good option.

Comment: Awesome, this did it for me! The only difference is my second embedded layout was a `RelativeLayout`, I'm not really familiar with the "`FrameLayout`" quite yet, so I wanted to stick with what I knew for now. Thanks very much.

Comment: Great! FrameLayout is just a bit more lightweight. It allows it's children to overlap each other but doesn't include all of the relative positioning options that are available in RelativeLayout.

Comment: That's good information too... Since this embedded layout is really just to allow me to put two entities in a single position sounds like the lighter `FrameLayout` is the way to go. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the icon you want to place on existing images and keep your previous LinearLayout to achieve this. Each component of your LinearLayout would be a custom layout (inflated):

```
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="img1_src"
/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgOverlap"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="img2_src"
    android:visibility="gone"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It appears not possible to use "layout_weight" in a RelativeLayout.
You could also consider a GridView and set its number of columns; each item of the GridView would be the inflated layout above.

Comment: There are few issues with this proposed solution - there is no weight on the RelativeLayout to ensure even spacing/scaling. Also the images are all fixed-size so they don't meet the requirement for scaling to the view. These issues are addressed in my earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do it programatically and tell them to be 33% of the screen width. Look at [`DisplayMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) and the attributes of each [`ImageView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) if you want to achieve this.

Comment: That's a neat tip. For my current purposes I'll be using embedded Layouts, but I'll keep that in mind for sure. I usually prefer do to things programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dragcircle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            android:tag="circle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dragtriangle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/triangle"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:tag="triangle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dragsquare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dragtriangle"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dragcircle"
            android:src="@drawable/square"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:tag="square" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it doesn't work. The thing is the images are large, if you place them on a portrait smartphone display (at the size they are) next to each other they would only fit 2 of the 3 shapes. This was solved in `LinearLayout` by the `layout_weight` in which each was scaled to 33% of the overall screen size thus making them fit nicely. Just positioning them correctly won't be enough, somehow they need to scale as well.

Comment: The edited answer still does not ensure uniform scaling. They will be uniformly positioned (left, center, right) but will render at their native size rather than scaling so that each occupies 1/3 of the width.